# Invoke java using JavaScript inside JavaFX. Is it possible?

Tags: java, javascript, javafx

I am using `WebEngine` & `WebView` from `JavaFX`. Now I want to execute Java using javascript running inside `WebEngine`.

My question is if it is possible to do so and if yes any hints.

I want do something like below

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  function runSampleJava() {
    var number = new java.lang.Integer(1234);
    var random = new java.util.Random();
    java.lang.System.out.println(random.nextInt());
  }
</script>
```

Now if I call the `runSampleJava()` inside `WebEngine` it will execute that code.

---

## Points to be noted

- This is not about `Rhino` JavaScript engine for java
- I know it is possible to inject java object, eg: `JSObject window = (JSObject) webEngine.executeScript("window");` and so on. But this is not what I am looking for.

Comment: Maybe this helps: http://www.nusphere.com/kb/jscoreref/javobj.html

Comment: @Fildor it is way beyond the problem :-(

Answer (score 4):

I didn't manage to create Java instances but the thing I managed to do is to push object instances created in Java into JavaScript and call back to them.

So my Java-Code looks like this:

```
JSObject win = (JSObject) engine.executeScript("window");
win.setMember("jHelper", new JavaHelper());
```

`JavaHelper` example ([must be public](https://blogs.oracle.com/javafx/entry/communicating_between_javascript_and_javafx#comment-1362464352708)):

```
public static class JavaHelper {
    public int newInteger(int input) {
        // ...
    }
    public Random newRandom() {
        // ...
    }
}
```

And then then in JavaScript:

```
function bla() {
  var number = jHelper.newInteger(1234);
  var random = jHelper.newRandom();
  // ...
}
```

You can see my work where I communicate between Java and JavaScript back and forth at https://github.com/tomsontom/fx-ide/tree/master/at.bestsolution.javafx.ide.editor and in action at http://tomsondev.bestsolution.at/2012/10/29/eclipsecon-javafx-demo-app-videos/

Comment: As I have already specified, I can do it already. And this is not exactly what I am looking for. 'Specially' I need to create object.

Comment: I guess it would be a major security problem if the webview would be allowed to create arbitary objects and pass back and forth real java objects. So all I found was allowed to get passed between JavaScript and Java in webview are primitive types and strings (I use JSON from communicating with the Java-Side)

Comment: Agreed with that security flaw.