# send text to javaFX from javascript by sending Java object to JavaScript

Tags: javascript, json, javafx, webview

EDIT: 
Adding eventhandlers for mouseclick and scroll on the webview will help fix this. My quess is that when zoomed or clicking(panning) the object widow changes.

```
         browser.addEventHandler(MouseEvent.MOUSE_CLICKED,
                new EventHandler<MouseEvent>() {
                    @Override public void handle(MouseEvent e) {
                    jsobj.setMember("java", new Bridge());
                    e.consume();
                    }
        });


        browser.setOnScroll(new EventHandler<ScrollEvent>() {
            @Override public void handle(ScrollEvent event) {
                jsobj.setMember("java", new Bridge());
                event.consume();
            }
        });
```

There seems to be a lot of questions and answers on this, but I cannot use them to solve this.

(https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/embedded-browser-tutorial/js-javafx.htm)

([Invoke java using JavaScript inside JavaFX. Is it possible?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14318472/invoke-java-using-javascript-inside-javafx-is-it-possible))*

Using a JavaFx WebView...

I am trying to send a `Java` object to `JavaScript`, than have `JavaScript` send that `object` back or run a `Java` method.

**I am waitng for...**

```
if (newState == Worker.State.SUCCEEDED)
```

Creating the java object and sending it  to JavaScript?

```
JSObject jsobj = (JSObject) browser.getEngine().executeScript("window");
                        jsobj.setMember("java", new Bridge());
```

What is the window function?

**EDIT:**

Here is the minimal version.

---

HTML

```
<html>
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no" />
<style type="text/css">
  html { height: 100% }
  body { height: 100%; margin: 0px; padding: 0px }
  #map_canvas { height: 100%; background-color: #666970; }
</style>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false">
</script>
<script type="text/javascript">

  function initialize() {
    var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(40.7128, -74.0059);
    var myOptions = {
      zoom: 14,
      center: latlng,
      mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.HYBRID,
      mapTypeControl: false,
      navigationControl: false,
      streetViewControl: false,
      backgroundColor: "#666970"
    };

    document.addMarker = function addMarker(x, y, name) {

        var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(x, y);

        var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
          label: name,
          position: latlng,
          map: document.map
        });

        marker.addListener('click', function() {
         java.exit2();
        });

      }

    document.geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
    document.map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"),myOptions);

  }
</script>
</head>
<body onload="initialize()">
  <div id="map_canvas" style="width:100%; height:100%"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

**java:**

```
package application;

import java.net.URL;

import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.beans.value.ChangeListener;
import javafx.beans.value.ObservableValue;
import javafx.concurrent.Worker;
import javafx.concurrent.Worker.State;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
import netscape.javascript.JSObject;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.layout.BorderPane;
import javafx.scene.web.WebView;


public class Main extends Application {
    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
        try {
            BorderPane root = new BorderPane();
            Scene scene = new Scene(root,400,400);

            WebView browser = new WebView();
            URL url = getClass().getResource("map.html");
            browser.getEngine().load(url.toExternalForm());
            root.setCenter(browser);

            browser.getEngine().getLoadWorker().stateProperty().addListener(
                    new ChangeListener<State>() {
                      @Override public void changed(ObservableValue ov, State oldState, State newState) {
                          if (newState == Worker.State.SUCCEEDED) {

                            browser.getEngine().executeScript(
                                    "document.addMarker("
                                            //lat
                                            +"40.7128"+","
                                            //long
                                            +"-74.0059"+","
                                            //marker name
                                            +"'"+"new_york"+"'"
                                            +")"
                                    );  

                            JSObject jsobj = (JSObject) browser.getEngine().executeScript("window");
                            jsobj.setMember("java", new Bridge());
                          }

                    }
             });

            primaryStage.setScene(scene);
            primaryStage.show();
        } catch(Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public class Bridge{
        public void exit2() {
            System.out.println("test");
        }
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

I get this error when trying to run program. As above.

If I change `line 41` where javafx sends the command to javascript, so the "name" is surrounded by `"'"`. It doesnt send an error but than it never calls the java class

As in.....

Error  and no label shown-->  `+"new_york"`

No Error- shows a label But, call to java class doesnt work--> `+"'"+"new_york"+"'"`

If I remove the name arg altogether it all works. But I need text on the label, that is sent from java to JavaScript.

Error:

```
Exception in thread "JavaFX Application Thread" netscape.javascript.JSException: ReferenceError: Can't find variable: new_york
    at com.sun.webkit.dom.JSObject.fwkMakeException(JSObject.java:137)
    at com.sun.webkit.WebPage.twkExecuteScript(Native Method)
    at com.sun.webkit.WebPage.executeScript(WebPage.java:1473)
    at javafx.scene.web.WebEngine.executeScript(WebEngine.java:982)
    at application.Main$1.changed(Main.java:34)
    at application.Main$1.changed(Main.java:1)
    at com.sun.javafx.binding.ExpressionHelper$SingleChange.fireValueChangedEvent(ExpressionHelper.java:182)
    at com.sun.javafx.binding.ExpressionHelper.fireValueChangedEvent(ExpressionHelper.java:81)
    at javafx.beans.property.ReadOnlyObjectPropertyBase.fireValueChangedEvent(ReadOnlyObjectPropertyBase.java:74)
    at javafx.beans.property.ReadOnlyObjectWrapper.fireValueChangedEvent(ReadOnlyObjectWrapper.java:102)
    at javafx.beans.property.ObjectPropertyBase.markInvalid(ObjectPropertyBase.java:112)
    at javafx.beans.property.ObjectPropertyBase.set(ObjectPropertyBase.java:146)
    at javafx.scene.web.WebEngine$LoadWorker.updateState(WebEngine.java:1260)
    at javafx.scene.web.WebEngine$LoadWorker.dispatchLoadEvent(WebEngine.java:1371)
    at javafx.scene.web.WebEngine$LoadWorker.access$1200(WebEngine.java:1253)
    at javafx.scene.web.WebEngine$PageLoadListener.dispatchLoadEvent(WebEngine.java:1240)
    at com.sun.webkit.WebPage.fireLoadEvent(WebPage.java:2434)
    at com.sun.webkit.WebPage.fwkFireLoadEvent(WebPage.java:2278)
    at com.sun.webkit.network.URLLoader.twkDidFinishLoading(Native Method)
    at com.sun.webkit.network.URLLoader.notifyDidFinishLoading(URLLoader.java:844)
    at com.sun.webkit.network.URLLoader.lambda$didFinishLoading$99(URLLoader.java:835)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$null$173(PlatformImpl.java:295)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runLater$174(PlatformImpl.java:294)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.InvokeLaterDispatcher$Future.run(InvokeLaterDispatcher.java:95)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication._runLoop(Native Method)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication.lambda$null$148(WinApplication.java:191)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

Comment: Bad stuff probably happens when you try to execute the javascript `var string = java.exit2();`, given that `exit2()` has `void` return type. Remove that line and see if it helps (or make `exit2()` return a `String`). What actually happens? As for *"What is the window function?"*: it's not a function but a variable. See, e.g. http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_window.asp (so in javascript in this context it's basically a variable representing the `WebView`).

Comment: @James_D Noting happens when the listener is called, I added another line of code where the map changes it's type from terrain to road map when the marker is clicked. So the listener works. I removed the var string = java...line and no errors or any system.out.printing. There were no errors either when I didn't have anything returning either.

Comment: I can only suggest you try to create a [MCVE]. There's not much chance of diagnosing this from the couple of snippets you posted.

Comment: @James_D added.

Comment: That's not really a [MCVE]. Can you make it something complete so I can just run it an see what happens? When and how does `addMarker()` get called?

Comment: @James_D sorry added that part.

Comment: I did the minimal modification to the code you posted to make it actually display a map, and when I clicked on the marker I got the expected output on the console. So I think you really need to [edit] this again so that it can be executed and produces the issues you describe. Right now it doesn't even compile, and once the compile errors are fixed, it's not executable, and even if you write a main method or similar to run the code you have, the code doesn't actually put anything on the screen. If I make all those changes, it works...

Comment: @James_D Ok thanks, Did you use FXML? It complies on my version, I must of taken something out or something when making it minimal. I will look into it.

Comment: The `document.addMarker(...)` part has a syntax error. The point is, if you create a new (minimal) project that actually compiles and runs, copying the relevant code into it, then verify it compiles and runs, then copy all the code from that minimal project in here, that wouldn't happen. I didn't use FXML, just copied your webview code into an actual application class that I could then run.

Comment: @James_D minimal updated...I see there is an error. In the "name" argument. I am not familiar with JavaScript much.  It works and bridge gets called when I remove the 3rd arg.  However when I try to run it with name: ReferenceError: Can't find variable: new_york.

Comment: The only error here is one that you introduced in your last edit in the HTML file. The JSON for your marker has a `;` after `label: name` instead of a `,`. (The previous version of your HTML was correct.) If you fix that, it works fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have an error in the JSON for the `marker` variable in the JavaScript:

```
    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
      label: name;
      position: latlng,
      map: document.map
    });
```

should be

```
    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
      label: name,
      position: latlng,
      map: document.map
    });
```

Additionally, you are registering the listener on the web engine *after* you ask the web engine to load the HTML. You have no guarantees that the listener will be installed when the loading completes (if loading is very quick, it could finish before the listener is installed, so the listener won't get called). Similarly, you are executing the script before you attach the callback. Here's a version of your `Main` class with a more logical ordering of the code (which I also cleaned up for simplicity and readability):

```
package application ;

import java.net.URL;

import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.concurrent.Worker;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.layout.BorderPane;
import javafx.scene.web.WebView;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
import netscape.javascript.JSObject;


public class Main extends Application {
    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
        try {
            BorderPane root = new BorderPane();
            Scene scene = new Scene(root,400,400);

            WebView browser = new WebView();
            root.setCenter(browser);

            browser.getEngine().getLoadWorker().stateProperty().addListener((ov, oldState, newState) -> {
                  if (newState == Worker.State.SUCCEEDED) {

                      JSObject jsobj = (JSObject) browser.getEngine().executeScript("window");
                      jsobj.setMember("java", new Bridge());

                      // document.addMarker(latitude, longitude, markerName) :
                      String script = "document.addMarker(40.7128, -74.0059, 'new_york')";

                      browser.getEngine().executeScript(script);  

                  }
            });

            URL url = getClass().getResource("map.html");
            browser.getEngine().load(url.toExternalForm());

            primaryStage.setScene(scene);
            primaryStage.show();
        } catch(Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public class Bridge{
        public void exit2() {
            System.out.println("test");
        }
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

Comment: Still does not work. Post updated. ...ReferenceError: Can't find variable: new_york

Comment: @Batty It works fine for me. (I have no idea why you think removing the quotes from the value for the label would work.) Your code is not ordered in a sensible way though: see the reordering in the edited answer.

Comment: James can you confirm if it still works after you scroll to zoom closer on the map or pan? It is not working when I do such. Sorry to kind of reopen the question.

Comment: Are you using the most recent code I posted? I ask cause I edited numerous times.

Comment: Here is a link to a screen recording that I filmed of my problem.  https://www.mediafire.com/?t9evu4fpq120iks

Comment: Edit found fix, added eventHandlers for mouseclick (click) and scroll. Than re-setmember on the JSObject. My guess is that if you move around google maps or zoom in the "object window" changes?

Comment: @Batty As I said, I couldn't reproduce the issue anyway, so I really can't comment on that.